# How to save a single .mat file of features for many images (loop for)?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I trained two-class-classification (`svmtrain`) with 15 features for 18 images and I have many objects in a single image. I want to save single .mat file of features of these images. My problem is when I run this code, I have just the variables of last image.

This is my code:

```
NbIm = size(names1,1);
n1 = 1;
n2 = NbIm;
for n = n1:n2
    %1- Read the original image
    %2- Processing :  Segmentation
    %3- characterization :
    [B3,L3,N3] = bwboundaries(ICellules); (see picture)
    CC = bwconncomp(L3);
    BW = bwlabel(L3);
    stats1 = regionprops(CC,'Area','Centroid','Eccentricity','Perimeter','ConvexArea','ConvexHull','ConvexImage','MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength','Orientation','Solidity','BoundingBox');
    for k = 1:length(B3),
        V = [];    glcm = [];
        V = Im_originale(BW==k);
        glcm = graycomatrix(V,'Offset',[2 0],'Symmetric', true);
        stats= graycoprops(glcm);
        Contrast_Cellule = stats.Contrast;
        Correlation_Cellule = stats.Correlation;
        Energy_Cellule = stats.Energy;
        Homogeneity_Cellule = stats.Homogeneity;
        Area_cellule = stats1(k).Area;
        Perimeter_cellule = stats1(k).Perimeter;
        Circularity_cellule = (4*pi*Area_cellule)/Perimeter_cellule^2;
        Centroid_cellule = stats1(k).Centroid;
        Compactness_cellule = Perimeter_cellule^2/(4*pi*Area_cellule);
        MajorAxis_cellule = stats1(k). MajorAxisLength;
        MinorAxis_cellule = stats1(k). MinorAxisLength;
        Orientation_cellule = stats1(k).Orientation;
        Eccentricity_cellule = stats1(k).Eccentricity;
        Solidity_cellule = stats1(k).Solidity;
        boundary3 = B3{k};
        [cc] = chaincode(boundary3);
        ai = cc.code;
        ai = ai.';
        output = calc_harmonic_coefficients(ai,30);
        Ampl = 0.5*sqrt((output(1)^2)+(output(2)^2)+(output(3)^2)+(output(4)^2));
        Feat(k,:) = [Area_cellule,Perimeter_cellule,Circularity_cellule,Compactness_cellule, Solidity_cellule,Eccentricity_cellule,MajorAxis_cellule,MinorAxis_cellule, Centroid_cellule,Ampl,Contrast_Cellule,Correlation_Cellule,Energy_Cellule,Homogeneity_Cellule];
    end
end
save('FeatTrain.mat', 'Feat');
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your code repeats `n2-n1` times the exact same operation. The problem is not with save, the problem is that `Feat` is always overwritten with the exact same values.

Comment: Hi Ander Biguri, thanks for your response...how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: We don't know, you provide no explanation nor data. Your code is not complete, so we can not help. Read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add code

Comment: @Ander Biguri  i edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you run the inner loop (`k=...`) you overwrite `Feat`, without ever saving it.

If you want to have a single variable for `Feat`, instead of saving multiple `.mat` files there are 2 ways to it:

1. If every time you run the inner loop the size of `Feat` is the same, you can make it a 3D matrix, by changing you line to `Feat(n-n1+1,k,:)=[...`. This will make a 3D matrix where each `Feat(n,:,:)` will be the features of each image.
2. If instead every time you run the inner loop `Feat` can change size, then use a cell array, as in `Feat{n-n1+1}(k,:)=[...`.

Comment: Hi, @Ander Biguri thanks for your response ...I change  Feat(k,:) = [... by Feat{n-n1+1}=[....   because the size of Feat can change from an image to another (e.g image number13 has 4 obejcts and number 12 has 2 objects and number one has one object ) and i test  my code for 13 images but I have  1x15 double for all images instead 4x15 or 2x15 for some images!

Comment: @ Ander Biguri I try your suggestion number 2 " If instead every time you run the inner loop Feat can change size, then use a cell array, as in Feat{n-n1+1}=[...." and i give you the result of your suggestion

Comment: @ Ander Biguri no problem ... i want to thank you for your help :) but it doesn't work :(

Comment: @ Ander Biguri can you help me please to resolve the peroblem because your  suggestion doesn't work :

Comment: @MarwaBraiki https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @ Ander Biguri should i accept the answer even if doesn't work?

Comment: @MarwaBraiki no, surely not! But it should work. I  am happy to help. Why i doesnt work? Your description is not sufficient. Also try to add a [mcve], in your case, I'd stress the word **Minimal**

Comment: WhenI i try your suggestion number 2 and i test my code for 13 images I have 1x15 double for all images instead 4x15 or 2x15 for some images! how can I insert an image in the comment to show you the result?

Comment: @ Ander Biguri I really appreciate your help in resolving the problem.Thanks so much for help :)